# How to create DataFrame from a Counter of tuples

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am kind of green at `pandas` and other scipy libraries, so I am not sure how to do this. I have a list of two-element tuples and I am counting the number of times the same tuple is found, or the reversed counterpart, hence the sorting:

```
In [24]: tuples
Out[24]:
[(1, 2),
 (1, 3),
 (1, 4),
 (2, 3),
 (2, 4),
 (3, 4),
 (2, 1),
 (3, 1),
 (4, 1),
 (3, 2),
 (4, 2),
 (4, 3)]

In [30]: count = Counter([tuple(sorted(t)) for t in tuples])

In [31]: count
Out[31]: Counter({(1, 2): 2, (1, 3): 2, (1, 4): 2, (2, 3): 2, (2, 4): 2, (3, 4): 2})
```

I am trying to create a `DataFrame` that essentially produces this output:

```
   1  2  3  4
1  0  2  2  2
2  2  0  2  2
3  2  2  0  2
4  2  2  2  0
```

Comment: Do you need you resulting/desired data set in excatly that way? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @MaxU it is just convenient to have the data in a `DataFrame` for the operations it has. For example, if I am in need to knowing how many times a given `t` is paired up with others, I can just `df[t]`. Having it in a `Counter` doesn't provide that indexing. That's just one example, there can be many others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about slightly different approach?

first let's create a DF from the sortedlist of tuples:

```
In [272]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(np.array(tuples), axis=1), columns=['c1','c2'])

In [273]: df
Out[273]:
    c1  c2
0    1   2
1    1   3
2    1   4
3    2   3
4    2   4
5    3   4
6    1   2
7    1   3
8    1   4
9    2   3
10   2   4
11   3   4
```

now we can count pairs using Pandas technique:

```
In [274]: res = df.groupby(['c1','c2']).size()

In [275]: res
Out[275]:
c1  c2
1   2     2
    3     2
    4     2
2   3     2
    4     2
3   4     2
dtype: int64
```

Accessing data in multi-index DF:

```
In [277]: res.loc[(1,2)]
Out[277]: 2

In [278]: res.loc[(2,4)]
Out[278]: 2
```

we can also unstack the resulting DF, which will give us:

```
In [279]: res.unstack(fill_value=0)
Out[279]:
c2  2  3  4
c1
1   2  2  2
2   0  2  2
3   0  0  2
```

Or [as proposed by @Dark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47673868/how-to-create-dataframe-from-a-counter-of-tuples/47674204?noredirect=1#comment82308297_47674204):

```
In [280]: pd.Series(count).unstack(fill_value=0)
Out[280]:
   2  3  4
1  2  2  2
2  0  2  2
3  0  0  2
```

Comment: As I mentioned I am kind of green with pandas. Can you briefly explain your answer?

Comment: Since theres already a counter variable we can also do `pd.Series(count).unstack(fill_value=0)`